# Cassandra ODBC Datastax working with Cassandra 2.1 but not 3.0 in Windows

Tags: cassandra, odbc, datastax

I have tried connecting to a remote Cassandra from Windows 10 using the latest Simba-Datastax ODBC Driver (trial version). I was successful with Cassandra 2.1 (I connected to a Cassandra docker actually) but failed with Cassandra 3.0.15 and 3.11. I have installed the driver and I am able to see it in the Windows Data sources tool (64 bits), under the System DSN tab.

When I specify the host, port and keyspace of my Cassandra 3.0 docker (exactly the same values that work allright for me with the Cassandra 2.1 docker) and press the "Test..." button to launch the connectivity test, I am getting a strange error that "**not even procol version 1 is available**".

According to [this](https://www.simba.com/resources/drivers/faq/cassandra/) web site, Simba says the driver is compatible with Cassandra 3.X. Could you think of any reason why this fails but 2.1 is successful? :-(

PS: I see other people complaining [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-datastax-odbc-driver-for-apache-cassandra) but with a different error message (No hosts available for the control connection)

Comment: Just a thought, but are you using Thrift?  Cassandra 3.x disables Thrift on 9160 by default.

Comment: @Aaron I am not sure what Thrift has to do with Cassandra... I used it in the past when I tried the Spark ODBC for a different purpose, nothing to do with Cassandra. Right now in the Windows Data sources when I click on the Cassandra ODBC driver, it only asks for the host and port, no reference to Thrift. Do you mean the default port in Cassandra 3.X has changed? I think it is 9042.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I think I was using a wrong version of the driver - I was using Datastax driver which apparently does not work for Cassandra 3.X. I have now downloaded the latest version of the ODBC driver from the [Simba website](https://www.simba.com/drivers/cassandra-odbc-jdbc/) (30-day trial version) and it is working :-)

The confusion came from the fact that I thought the Datastax driver and the Simba driver were the same as I read somewhere that "Simba and Datastax have partnered to develop a driver...".

Thank you very much Aaron anyway.